# Browsers that support Amazon S3 CORS

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I need to upload files directly to S3 from Client. I found this is possible with Amazon S3 CORS. I need to know the list of browsers that support Amazon S3 CORS.

Can anyone list the browsers along with versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CORS only comes into play with AJAX requests.

Normal browsers can do a normal HTTP POST form.

If your backend is in PHP, you can use the AWS SDK for PHP to prepare the signature and hidden fields. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.Model.PostObject.html